# Open source android image resize library

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I need a java library (open source) for android. Can someone recommend me one?

I need it to resize images (main reason) but I might need it for some other image manipulations too.

Comment: ImageMagick may be a good thing for you... check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832217/compile-imagemagick-for-android-using-ndk

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize an image in Java - Any Open Source Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/resize-an-image-in-java-any-open-source-library)

Comment: For resizing in Android, check this one: https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Answer (score -4, accepted):

For thumbnails give a try to http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator

Comment: Thhumbnailator will not run on Android, as it requires Java 2D and Java Image I/O which are not available on Android. (Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the library.)

Comment: Oh k. My bad ! I would request for no more negative votes, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can try OpenCV for android

[Try here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3afFdP49HBv1QJ%3awww.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Windows.pdf%20&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShmVCBFhS3U_hOocTHvzlQHwinx26bK4MsAipfiKZnZolava6NecwJUrjLZNACzqM2j-1La2NX-vp8fwL_upop2m2P4m4zB952XyvmbgUqK1qTP_Hsx3D-bGjErhKa463vkFKzr&sig=AHIEtbSeT28pGVZKyQzEfvlMqQ0EVXfjVg)

[Try here also](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android)

Comment: Thanks for links, but OpenCV is too big for what I need to do. I'm looking for something small... one file library, something I can write by myself if I had time (I don't have). Do you know any thumbnails generator for android? This should do the job in my case?