# Building ImageMagick for Android NDK with more image format support

Tags: android-ndk, imagemagick

I'm starting from this project:

https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick

which I found from this question:

[Compile Imagemagick for Android using NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832217/compile-imagemagick-for-android-using-ndk)

I have been able to successfully build ImageMagick for the NDK except that it doesn't support any image format at all.

I'm really not sure how to include more formats and it seems that at least jpeg and tiff should be supported based on what I see in the project referenced above. Does anyone have some insight into how to get it built with support for at least jpeg, gif, tiff and png?