# ViewPager for displaying PDF pages

Tags: android, pdf, android-viewpager

I'm trying to create a book app in android, the pages of the book come from a PDF file.

I was able to use a PagerAdapter & ViewPager for displaying images, is there anyway I can convert a PDF pages into bitmaps?

I really don't know where to start!!!

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You should begin by making some research . you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14393561/3014036) .

See also this links :
 [How to convert a PDF page to an image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698360/how-to-convert-a-pdf-page-to-an-image-in-android) 
 [Need help to convert a Pdf page into Bitmap in Android Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814758/need-help-to-convert-a-pdf-page-into-bitmap-in-android-java)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are some set of libraries you can use

http://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfsdk/

http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/

https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

Comment: Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library doesn't provide pinch zoom facility by default.Is there a way to get it ?