# Convert Pdf page into image using mupdf

Tags: android, pdf, mupdf

I googled, but I cannot find a solution to do this.

I am in need of showing an image thumbnail view from a PDF's first page without opening it. The PDF file will be available in my mobile itself.

Installing another external library is not possible. Mupdf is available.

Comment: is it important to use muPDF, or is any way to convert the first page to an image sufficient?

Comment: @user1587329 it's fine. no issues at all. but i cannot switch any other lib to render. ..thanks

Comment: You can't render the first page of a PDF file without opening the PDF file....

Comment: @KenS we can do this by gotopage() method in MuPdfCore.java

Comment: Not without opening the PDF file. MuPDF has to open the PDF file and read it in order to render the page.

Comment: Go to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698360/how-to-convert-a-pdf-page-to-an-image-in-android/63684103#63684103

Answer (score 2):

Finally i done this, by,

drawPage(bp, 0, size.x, size.y, 0, 0, size.x, size.y, new Cookie());

it'll help you to render first page of PDF as BitMap. This method implemented in MuPDFCore.java.

PointF pageSize = getPageSize(0);
            float mSourceScale = Math.max(w/pageSize.x, h/pageSize.y);

```
        Point size = new Point((int)(pageSize.x*mSourceScale), (int)(pageSize.y*mSourceScale));
        final Bitmap bp = Bitmap.createBitmap(size.x, size.y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        drawPage(bp, 0, size.x, size.y, 0, 0, size.x, size.y, new Cookie());
        storeImageIntoLocal(bp,filePath);//To Do my custom method to store bitmap into local
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without muPDF, have a look at [How to convert a PDF page to an image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698360/how-to-convert-a-pdf-page-to-an-image-in-android). The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26613590/1587329) gives a link to [PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html) (available from API 21). You probably use it like this:

> ```
>  // create a new renderer
>  PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(getSeekableFileDescriptor());
>
>  // render the page
>  Page page = renderer.openPage(i).render(mBitmap, null, null, Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
>
>  // do stuff with the bitmap
>
>  // close the page
>  page.close();
>
>  // close the renderer
>  renderer.close();
> ```