# Base64 Pdf into WebView on Android

Tags: java, android, base64

Hi guys I have to view a pdf in base64 in a WebView to do so I used the code below but it does not work! How can I visualize it? I tried this solution but it does not seem to work, nothing is shown in the WebView! What can it be?

**Java Code:**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Button btnGeneraRapportino = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttongenera_rapportino);
    final WebView img= (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.WebView_Rapportino);

    btnGeneraRapportino.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Rapportino r = new Rapportino();
            String ImageBase64 = r.GeneraRapportinoPrivato("prova"); //This method return String with pdf into Base64
            try {
                String urlString = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(ImageBase64);
                String mimeType = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("MimeType");
                WebSettings settings = img.getSettings();
                settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
                String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(urlString.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                img.loadData(urlString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.print("Errore: "+ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want to display from URL or local?

Comment: @MilanPansuriya the r.GeneraRapportinoPrivato(..) method returns a base64 string from a node.js server, I would like to show the pdf locally in a WebView

Comment: for webview you have pdf file url or are you display from assets folder?

Comment: @MilanPansuriya he say he got base64 image of pdf file, so the process is to convert base64 string to image file, save to local or temp folder then show it to webview

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira exact is a pdf file not an image!

Comment: @MilanPansuriya

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Do you have any idea how I could do?

Comment: @riki you cannot show pdf in android webview. convert it to image first

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I have already tried this type of solution, but I have not found a way to do it correctly! with java into android

Comment: @riki try to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698360/how-to-convert-a-pdf-page-to-an-image-in-android

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I read the link, the libraries used in that link I do not know anymore supported!