# Using ImageMagick in my android application

Tags: java, android, image-processing, imagemagick

I cant figure out how to use ImageMagick on Android. Please can someone guide me how to get started? what should i download or what should i do? I have searched numerous stack questions as well as many sites but still not clear about what to do.

Comment: Have you looked into https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick and https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick? I digged around and it seems like getting ImageMagick to work on Android involves compiling the library using NDK yourself or using pre-existing ports such as the links I provided. I suggest taking a thorough read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832217/compile-imagemagick-for-android-using-ndk.

Comment: Thank you @Barney Hsiao but now i am trying to implement OpenCV as suggested by some people on stack.